# Best way to share GraphQl schema for code generation

Tags: docker-compose, graphql, microservices, code-generation

I have this microservice project where I want to try a client-driven schema-first approach. And because I'm lazy I want to have the necessary code to be generated.

For the Angular frontend I'm using the `graphql-codegen` tools and for the backend I'm using the `graphql-codegen-maven-plugin` plugin. Both generate code that I can work with and make developing, especially syncing the front- and backend models, much easier.

Because I'm using Docker the backend and the frontend are separate images that are composed using `docker-compose`. But sharing the schema turns out to be challenging.

Currently, I just symlink'ed the schema from the frontend into the backend. That works fine when running the applications natively from the command line or the IDE. But it won't work when using the Docker commands.

I also thought about using git submodules, but because I'm using a mono repo, that would not be very useful.

I'm trying to avoid using a script to copy the schema file from the client to the server directory, because I don't want to have this implied knowledge, that you only can edit the schema file inside one module. Having a symlink is kinda neat to that.

Is there any useful approach that doesn't come with to much trade offs, a best practice I'm not aware of? Or am I completely wrong with my kind of thinking and generating frontend and backend code should be done somewhat different?

Comment: Define your schema in your backend, use apollo client codegen to generate typings for your frontend. I use typescripts-typedefs to make generating typings/typedefs in backend easier.